# Malware warning at opening my pages on android

Tags: android, html, css, wordpress, web-hosting

I am somewhat new developer and I ran in to a problem with my code or my server or something and I don't understand.
I created simple parallax (html and css only) landing page and transferred files to my web host. I have there about 10 WordPress sites.
Opens fine in Chrome Firefox and Edge but on my android (note 5) chrome it will give me a malware warning. Same in android native internet explorer. Same happens in my wife's phone and on another android device and nokia tablet (windows OS).
I removed files and installed WP and made simple landing page...no problems. same thing with domain and sub domain.
bestjetsinc.com
boudoirtampabay.lx-photography.com
can someone please help. I want this to work.
ed

Answer (score 1):

I doubt your html/css website is the problem. My guess would be one of your WordPress websites is compromised. Try adding one of the free WordPress security plugins to them (such as wordfence), and do a scan. It will probably return something.

Comment: Thanks for this. I managed to solve this with help of my server company. I think your answer would also lead me to the solution, so thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to ht_access.bk in your hosting environment.
5 years ago a have used WP site that injected redirection in ht_access when request comes from mobile device. Sometime in last 5 years the IP where request was redirected went offline and problem was revealed. I have never used my WP sites to collect information from my visitors so no personal information was revealed. Thanks God. 
So coders here is another reason why your client should hire you to develop their online presence instead of downloading template with some mean code.

I removed bad code from ht_access.bk and now everything works like it supposed to. I spent two days on this and was about to drop my hosting company.
I am smiling again!